# How to bake Particle System in Blender 2.79

Tags: particles

I'm using Blender 2.79 and there no longer appears to be a Cache tab under Particle System settings. How can I bake a particle system so that when Blender crashes I don't have to start rendering from the beginning? I'm not looking to turn the particles into real objects because I am not using physics, I need each dupli object to appear in sequence from the emitter object. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For those having the same problem: The cache tab disappears when the physics are set to "none" because apparently without physics, there is nothing to calculate and save to the disk. Because I was after the sporadic and stationary emergence of particles from the emitter, I found that using a Particle System of type "hair" instead of "emitter" will suffice when I animate the "length" option in the clump settings. It's not ideal because they all emerge at once, but until I find a better way, this will have to do! Please comment if there is a better fix to this!

Answer (score 1):

[Cache](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/cache.html#cache) is indeed located in the [Particles system panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/particle_system_panel.html#particle-system-panel) located in the properties editor as shown in the image below. It is located directly below *emission* settings:

[image]

Comment: I've updated my post to show that no, indeed there is no Cache tab

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And I finally figured out, that you only have to check the box under Hair Dynamics (under Emission) and then the Cache-Option appears underneath. 
There is no need for animating the particle system! Which indeed wouldn´t make sense if you only use the particle-option to distribute a specific object in your scene.

Answer (score 0):

haven't try 2.79 but the cache particle bake is okay in blender version 2.80.you might want to upgrade it

[image]